# Unable to run applescript from emacs-lisp

Tags: org-babel

I have the following code block, which I am trying to execute from org-babel:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp

  (let ((h (nth 5 (org-heading-components))))
    (do-applescript (format "tell application \"Calendar\"
       activate
       set s to current date
       set f to s + 30 * minutes
       tell calendar \"activities\"
         make new event with properties {summary:%s, start date:s, end date:f}
       end tell
   end tell" h)))

#+End_SRC
```

The applescript bit works fine, on its own. But when I run this from org-babel, I get the following error:

```
Expected expression but found ":".
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Line 1 should have used `nth 4` not 5, which is why Emacs complained about a `:`. Also, the `%s` needs to be quoted. Here is the finished code:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp

  (let ((h (nth 4 (org-heading-components))))
    (do-applescript (format "tell application \"Calendar\"
       activate
       set s to current date
       set f to s + 30 * minutes
       tell calendar \"activities\"
         make new event with properties {summary:\"%s\", start date:s, end date:f}
       end tell
   end tell" h)))

#+End_SRC
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer. Otherwise, the question will keep getting bumped to the home page now and then, as happened just now. There is a tick mark you click on to accept the answer.